# How to set an environment variable for a shell from ant script?

Tags: shell, ant

I have a shell script user.sh that calls an ant script. The ant script prompts for some user input like

```
<input message="Enter the username" addproperty="my.user" />
```

I want to set an environment variable USER for the script user.sh from the ant script with the input value entered.
I tried to do it like this:

```
<property environment = env />
<property name = env.USER value=my.user />
```

But it is not setting the environment variable in the shell script.
How to set it in the parent shell script which was used to invoke the ant script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, `ant` is sub process of shell. It is not possible to set parent process shell's environment variable from sub process. Other options are .

1. Accept the user input from shell and set the variable.
2. Write the obtained value  from ant into a file, and source that file from
       parent shell. (some what like a call back).